# How to evaluate phrases for auto population to another column?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, gs-vlookup

What I'm looking for:

I want phrases in **Sheet 2 - Column C**, to determine whether or not it falls under the Counties in **Sheet 1 - Column D**. If found under **Column D(Sheet 1)** based on the county it belongs to, it would populate **Sheet 2 - Column F** with the Cities from **Column B(Sheet 1)**.

How would I achieve this with formulas? Please and thank you!

**Illustrated below:**

[image]

Comment: @player0 Here you go https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10vrK14HjUzFNTbf6lp3luMsc2lYErAM8KpnOUezGd2g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: Can you please request for access since this sheet is on a work account? Please and thank you, once you do, I can give you access immediately.

Comment: @player0 Sorry, forgot to tag you. Please request for access since this is on a work account.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C2:C, 
 QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY("♂"&UPPER(TRIM(IFERROR(
 SPLIT(Sheet1!D3:D, ","))))&"♀"&Sheet1!B3:B, , 999^99)), , 999^99), "♂")), "♀"), 
 "where Col2 is not null", 0), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you very much for this and taking the time. If you have the time to go over this so that I can understand I would be grateful and so that I don't waste your time just taking a formula and not learn anything from it. I want to continuously progress.

Please explain the use of the following:
'Split' - 
'Query' -
'♂' (How did you even get these?) - 
'♀' -  
'999^99' - 

Everything else I somewhat understand. 
Again, Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I already created some notes and scenarios to see how I can come up with my complex versions of this same set up. Thank you for your time, have a great day!

Comment: **full explanation here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OG4JYmcozBBnFZE8bw7aWWa1JyKgX4lwpZiHWyhv91U/edit#gid=1896351475**